# How can two sibling components interact with each other?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a simple graph. The graph just has nodes and edges and nodes can be dragged around. Nodes have a block on the front/back for input/output edges. Html looks like this:

Graph component

```
<div class='graph'>
    <my-node *ngFor="let node of nodes"></my-node>
</div>
```

myNode Component

```
<div class='node'>
    <div class="frontConnector"></div>
    <div class="backConnector"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to figure out how to drag an edge from one node to another. If I try and set a mousedown/mouseup listener on the connector, I don't know how to figure out what the connecting node is. If I try and set the mouse listener on the node in the graph component, I can't check if the mousedown was on the connector vs. some other part of the node.

The answer to this will also likely drive how edges actually work. Should edges be a property on the node, or should connections be their own thing that just track which nodes they're attached to?

Comment: Did you try looking for an answer in the Component interaction chapter?
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: I don't believe this sibling relationship is described there; it's all parent/child

Comment: Siblings communication can be child-parent-child like explained in the link above or like as explained between unrelated components also explained in the linked docs. There is a special case but I don't know if it applies to your case (I'll post an answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use template variables to communicate between siblings directly

```
<my-comp-a #a></my-comp-b>
<my-comp-b (click)="a.doSomething()"></my-comp-b>
```

There is no other special support for direct siblings communication.

For all other methods see https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: my graph component has N my-node components. I'm using *ngFor. How would your example work in this case?

Comment: I guess it wouldn't because all elements would have the same template variable and its scope would be limited to within itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a service that exposes an Observable. The Observable would emit whenever something important occurs, using the `share()` operator so each output is emitted just once to all subscribers

To make tell the service that something occurred, give it a method that you can call with data. The method would cause the Observable to emit.

I would inject that service in all the sibling components.  Each child can then subscribe to the Observable to listen for changes.

When something occurs in child 1, call the class method with info about what happened. This will cause the service Observable to emit.  All other children will receive notification.  The concerned child can then act on the notification while the others can ignore it.